# How do I access a GPS from Windows IoT on Rasperry Pi?

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi, iot

I have done this when running Debian using gpsd. But when running Windows IoT preview...what is a way to get the NMEA sentences off an attached GPS (on the USB port). Is that kind of support around yet?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this support is not yet available but it is being actively developed. Furthermore the Geolocator API is broken. Unfortunately I don't have an ETA for this but its coming.

Mark Radbourne (MSFT)